# Async safe threadpool

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, atomic

I'm trying the write a threadpool that can safely be added inside a signal handler or in code [forked](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) by multithreaded code. Are there any corner cases that would cause this code to fail? What could be done to improve this code?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_WORKERS 16

struct threadpool
{
    _Atomic(int) idle;
    void *(*func)(void*);
    sem_t sem;
    void * arg;
    int id;
    pthread_t thread;
};

struct threadpool threads[MAX_WORKERS] = {0};

void *Worker(void *arg)
{
    int * t = (int*)arg;
x:
    sem_wait(&threads[*t].sem);
    __sync_synchronize();
    threads[*t].func(threads[*t].arg);
    threads[*t].idle = false;
    goto x;
}

bool ThreadPoolNew()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
        threads[i].id = i;
        sem_init(&threads[i].sem, 0, 0);
        pthread_create(&threads[i].thread, NULL, Worker, &threads[i].id);
    }
    return true;
}

bool ThreadPoolAddTask(void *(*entry)(void*), void * arg, bool retry)
{
    _Atomic(bool) found = false;
x:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
        if (__sync_val_compare_and_swap(&threads[i].idle, 0, 1) == 0) {
            threads[i].func = entry;
            threads[i].arg = arg;
            __sync_synchronize();
            sem_post(&threads[threads[i].id].sem);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found == false && retry == true) {
        goto x;
    }

    return found;
}

void * t1(void *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i += 2;     
        printf("%i\n", i);
        sleep(5);
    }
}

void * t2(void *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i += 3;
        printf("%i\n", i);
        sleep(5);
    }
}

//TESTER CODE
//gcc -pthread list.c

int main(void)  
{
    ThreadPoolNew();
    ThreadPoolAddTask(t2, NULL, 1);
    ThreadPoolAddTask(t1, NULL, 1);
    sleep(60);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **idle**

  As coded, `idle` is `false` when thread is in fact idle. Either rename it to `working`/`running`/`whatever active` or swap the `true`/`false` values.
- **Control flow**

  Unless I am missing something crucial, there is no need to `goto` neither in `Worker` nor in `ThreadPoolAddTask`.

  Similarly, `found` seems redundant:

  ```
  do {
      for (i = 0, i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
          if (...) {
              ....;
              return true;
          }
      }
  } while (retry);
  return false;
  ```

  As a side note, `retry` shouldn't be handled here. It is a caller business logic when and how to retry. I don't see any value added.
- **Worker argument**

  I recommend passing a pointer to a worker instead of pointer to its index. It simplifies both `ThreadPoolNew` and `Worker` to:

  ```
  void *Worker(void *arg)
  {
      struct threadpool * t = (int*)arg;
  x:
      sem_wait(t->sem);
      __sync_synchronize();
      t->func(t->arg);
      t->idle = false;
      goto x;
  }

  bool ThreadPoolNew()
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORKERS; i++) {
          sem_init(&threads[i].sem, 0, 0);
          pthread_create(&threads[i].thread, NULL, Worker, &threads[i]);
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

  and removes the need for `thread.id`. BTW, notice that `assert(threads[i].id == i)` always holds, so you may post your semaphore as

  ```
      sem_post(&threads[i].sem);
  ```
- You may want to `__sync_synchronize()` after announcing the thread idle (there is no barrier between setting `idle` and subsequent `sem_wait`).